# Spring boot error UnsupportedClassVersionError with Intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have an application in Spring Boot with Tomcat.
I needed to make update in my repository maven, and after this, started with this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartScopeInitializer
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:423)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:402)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:393)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:260)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:236)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
> at br.coopercarga.com.br.SistemacolaborativoApplication.main(SistemaApplication.java:23)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/RestartScopeInitializer has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
> at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:415)
> ... 7 more

My java version:

[image]

Project Structure:

[image]

[image]

My run configuration:

[image]

My pom.xml (maven)

```
    <groupId>br.xxx.com.br</groupId>
<artifactId>sistemacolaborativo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.13.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-jmx-remote</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.75</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.20.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <!--<version>2.0.0.M6</version>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.coopercarga.com.br</groupId>
        <artifactId>sistemacolaborativo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>13.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My SistemaApplication.java

```
import br.xxxxx.com.br.TokenFilter.TokenFilter;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SistemaApplication {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean getFilterJWT() {
        FilterRegistrationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        frb.setFilter(new TokenFilter());
        frb.addUrlPatterns("/#/*");

        return frb;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SistemaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I've already tried updating Java, and reconfiguring my project, but without success, I did several searches, but no solution worked, so any help I'd appreciate.

Comment: What is your `JAVA_HOME` variable? Does it point to the same JDK as your project in Intellij?

Comment: You are mixing different Spring Boot versions that will not work. And as already mentiond Spring Boot 3+ requires JDK17 at minimum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent is Springboot 2.x but then you added Springboot 3 dependencies, that require Java 17 https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0